# Is it necessary to upgrade to 15.10 from 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

I am using 14.04 and is working without any issue but software updater informs me that a new version 15.10 is available.

I know that new version will have some new exciting features and looks would be great but they may not be very useful to all.

I am also bit hesitant as small software updates breaks the system sometimes.

So shall I upgrade and what will happen if I don't upgrade?

Regards,SHK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 100% NO.  Do not upgrade to 15.10.  14.04 is an LTS release which means you'll have full support till 2019.  15.10 is not LTS and support for it has already ended since July 28.

The only release you could consider upgrading to is 16.04 but if you're ok with 14.04, you can definitely continue using it without hesitation.